# What is the "topology induced from $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the set $S$ of all the points in the plane of coordinates
> $(x,sin(1/x))$ for $x \in (0,1]$. Then, take the closure of it
> ${S'}$ and show that this closed set, viewed as a metric space with
> the topology induced from $\mathbb R^2$, is connected but not arcwise
> connected.

What is the "topology induced from $\mathbb R^2$"? I am taking analysis right now and so we barely covered topology so please explain in the context of metric spaces. BTW, what are the limit points? Is it $(0,y)$, where $y \in \{0,1,-1\}$?

Comment: The topology induced from $\Bbb R^2$ is the subspace topology, i.e. $S\subseteq (X,\tau)$ has the subspace topology $\tau_S$ when $A\in \tau_S\Leftrightarrow \exists B\in \tau, A=S\cap B$. If $X$ is a metric space, then the subspace topology is the topology induced on $S$ by the restriction of the metric to $S\times S$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299036/what-is-induced-topology); it’s also called the [relative topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is induced topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299036/what-is-induced-topology)

Comment: This is known as the "topologist's sine curve."

Comment: @RobertShore Is the only limit point $(0,0)$? Is $(0,-1), (0,1)$ limit points? and hence part of the closure?

Comment: What do you think?  Have you drawn a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The induced topology on $S'$ is just the subspace topology it inherits from $\mathbb R^2$.

That is, open sets in $S'$ are of the form $U\cap S'$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Okay, I remember covering this actually very briefly though my intuition isn't great. How do you recommend I proceed / what should I think about?